# Sharepoint 2013 Search Schema and search phrase

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search

I'm using Sharepoint Server 2013 Enterprise.

I have a list with 5 columns: Question, Answer, Facebook, Twitter, Status. All is multiline of text (text plain). 
I created a Managed Properties with name: "QuestionSearch" that mapping with 4 columns: Question, Answer, Facebook, Twitter.

So when I typed a search text is only 1 word, It works. But when I typed a phrase for search, It only search first word with filter "QuestionSearch" and search everything with other words.

Example:
Search text: *QuestionSearch:question*
and result ok with all the items have question word in 4 columns.
But with search text: *QuestionSearch:question demo*
The result is search "Question" text in 4 columns and search "demo" text in every columns.

So How do I search only in 4 columns with a phrase?

Thanks,

Comment: Try with QuestionSearch:"question demo"

Comment: @eVT please put that as an answer, not a comment, as it is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with `QuestionSearch:"question demo"`

That will search all words in that managed property(with mapped 4 columns).

If you search like this `QuestionSearch:question demo` that space between two words is like "AND" and searching all columns with word "demo"

Comment: But when I search QuestionSearch:"question demo", It only return the result exact phrase "question demo" and not "question and between demo text".

Answer (score 0):

Try : `QuestionSearch:question%2bdemo` in query text to get the desired results.
Here the space is getting encoded.

You can also use [SP Search Query Tool](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) to try and build desired queries.

Comment: This won't work as that will be counted as two distinct terms and yield the problem OP has outlined. Besides encoding is not required. @eVT provided the correct solution.